# How to insert eventid calendar into calendar description using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have script below to create calendar events from google form. The script working for now but I want to record its own eventid into that event description. Then when user want to delete their own event, they can refer into description and I will have another form for user to delete their own event using this eventid.

```
//var calendarId = "id@group.calendar.google.com";

var typeId = 2;
var nameId = 3;
var startDtId = 4;
var endDtId = 5;
var emailId = 6
var eventId = 7

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
var lr = rows.getLastRow();

function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {

  var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr, startDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr, endDtId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange(lr, nameId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange(lr, emailId, 1, 1).getValue();
  var desc = "text here" + "\n" + "text here" + "\n" + "text here"; //<--possible to insert eventid here?
  var title = sheet.getRange(lr, typeId, 1, 1).getValue() + " " + name;
  //var type = sheet.getRange(lr, typeId, 1, 1).getValue();

  createAllDayEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,desc,email);
}

function createAllDayEvent(calendarId, title, startDt, endDt, desc, email) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  var email = email;
  var title = title;
  //var type = type;

  var event = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, start, end, {
        description : desc,
        guests: email
    });
  event.setGuestsCanModify(true);

  var eventid = event.getId();
  sheet.getRange(lr, eventId, 1, 1).setValue(eventid);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to add the event ID to the description when the event is created using your showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var eventid = event.getId();
```

#### To:

```
var eventid = event.getId();
event.setDescription(desc + "\n" + eventid);
```

In this modification, the event ID is added as a new line in the description. So, please modify `\n` for your actual situation.

Or, if you want to put only the event ID, please modify as follows.

```
var eventid = event.getId();
event.setDescription(eventid);
```

Or, if you want to use the event ID using Calendar API, please use the event ID as `var eventid = event.getId().split("@")[0];`.

- When this modification is reflected in your showing script, when the event is created, the event ID retrieved from the created event is put to the description.

#### Reference:

- [setDescription(description)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setDescription(String))